# Select OrderBy does not seem to work on LINQ Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have defined a List collection:

```
public List<PacketToSend> Packets = new List<PacketToSend>();
```

The PacketToSend Class Object is:

```
public class PacketToSend
{
    public byte[] JPEG;
    public string LicenseKey;
    public Int64 TS;
    public Int64 FrameLag;
    public Int64 NetworkLag;
    public DateTime RelayDiff ;      
}
```

I add to this collection on the OnMessage event on my server's web-scokect connection:

```
Packets.Add(new PacketToSend
{
    FrameLag = frameLag,
    RelayDiff = DateTime.Now,
    TS = timeStamp,
    JPEG = packet2,
    LicenseKey = licenseKey.ToUpper(),
    NetworkLag = 0
});
```

The only value that matters for this question is the TS field.

I have experienced that the order of the messages are sometimes not correct so, I use this code to get the 'youngest' TS:

```
var min = Packets.OrderBy(m => m.TS).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now I have experienced (especially when the List is over a count of 50 that the 'youngest' TS does not return.

I was going to try and use 'Min' instead like so:

```
var min2 = Packets.OrderBy(m => m.TS).Min();
```

But of course I get the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.
```

Any ideas why the 1st way of doing it does not always work and perhaps a suggestion as to how to use the 2nd way of doing it?

N.B.

Further info.

I wait until I get a buffer of TS's for say 5 seconds before trying to get the earliest 1.  I know people will suggest using Locks but I have experienced a slow-down in my FPS which is 20fps needed. Also, I have used the Concurrency Collection but I experienced missed frames

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your first method, what makes you think it's not working?

Comment: @DavidG I write the result to console and look at the value it returns but also the list of values 'left' in the List and it definitely does not return the 'youngest' TS :(

Comment: You can't call IEnumerable<T>.Min() if T doesn't implement IComparable. OrderBy uses the supplied lambda expression to order the elements, but after that is done, there is no way for your program to know that the resulting list is sorted, or indeed, how to find out what "least" means in the context of `PacketToSend` objects

Comment: @kai yes, you are quite correct. I just wanted to see/know if there was another approach :)

Comment: With your concurrency issues, is it possible the values 'left' has changed since the min value was obtained?

Comment: @DavidG, yes I had looked at that and whilst I expect a few frames to have been added after my expression has executed the reality is that over 50% are younger (which can be about 100 TS's). I think it is down to the concurrency issue but ways around it I cannot find without the 'affects' of slowness I experienced

Comment: .. meaning that because the List is being accessed on 2 threads it 'throws' the result completely

Comment: Then surely then youngest at the time of calling `FirstOrDefault` is fine for you and anything added after doesn't matter anyway? Try taking a clone of the list as a test to see if that is the issue.

Comment: @DavidG Not sure I follow :) the 'youngest' TS is not being returned.

Comment: taking a Clone or piping  the contents to the Console would give me the same result I would have thought?

Comment: I have just been called into a meeting!!

Comment: Take a clone of the list, get the youngest one from that list and then output the cloned list to console. You should now see your youngest item is indeed the correct one.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks it now seems to have worked.

Comment: Hmm, so it was just a concurrency thing?

Comment: I think something weird is happening with the web socket -buffer - framework I am using - Fleck. I restarted the app and it consistently worked. Weird.  I am now getting another issue with my clients being flooded with the relayed data (which are jpegs).